# Getting values from a data table in a different tab

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable, tabs, save

I have a form that requires user to upload an excel file. This excel file has a column that can include multiple dates. Once user chooses the proper excel file to upload, the form creates tabs (for loop) for each different date the imported excel file has. (in each tab is a data table).

The table consists columns of a reference date and locations (Canada and all provinces) and the vales for Canada and all provinces are "population".

After this, I have a button to save into an SQL database. And it works. But the issue I am having is that the save button only saves the LAST data table from the last time. The save button is meant to save all data tables (all the tabs)

I had the idea of storing the first data tables in a temp table, but I couldn't figure out how to retrieve the values in the first data table in the earlier tabs.

Is there a (better) solution trying to save more than just the last data table in the last tab on to the SQL database?
 ..
the Save button action handler

```vb
Private Sub btnSaveDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveDB.Click
    If Not sumDts Is Nothing Then
        If Save() Then 'Save is successful
            'Say save is successful
            MsgBox("save done.")

        End If
    Else MsgBox("Nothing To save In DB.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error message.")
    End If
    'MsgBox("Nothing To save In DB.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error message.")

End Sub
```

not too much code for the button really

```vb
Public Function Save() As Boolean
    Dim bSave As Boolean = False
    Dim comSql As New SqlCommand
    comSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim myTrans As SqlTransaction = Nothing
    Dim MaxCompEstID As Object = Nothing
    Dim compID As Integer
    myTrans = DatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    myCommand.Connection = DatabaseConnection
    myCommand.Transaction = myTrans
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Try
        comSql.Connection = DatabaseConnection
        comSql.Transaction = myTrans

        myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.T_LFS_PROV_Component_Total_NPR (CompEstID, ProvCode, population)"

        comSql.CommandText = "SELECT CompEstID FROM T_LFS_PROV_Component_Total_NPR " &
                        " (UPDLOCK) WHERE CompEstID IN " &
                        " (SELECT LastID=MAX(CompEstID) FROM T_LFS_PROV_Component_Total_NPR)"

        MaxCompEstID = comSql.ExecuteScalar()
        If IsNothing(MaxCompEstID) Or IsDBNull(MaxCompEstID) Then
            compID = 1
        Else
            compID = CType(MaxCompEstID, Double) + 1
        End If

        SaveComponent(myCommand, compID)
        myTrans.Commit()
        bSave = True


    Catch ex As Exception

        myTrans.Rollback()
        MsgBox("An exception of type " & ex.GetType().ToString() &
                   " Message : " & ex.Message.ToString() &
                   " : was encountered while attempting to SAVE  ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Save LFS NPR")
        Debug.Print("...")
    End Try

    Return bSave
End Function
```

compID should be related to each date. in this example, the excel file has two different dates. (that's why there's two different tabs) maybe linking compID to each date will solve my problem

this is the second part of save

```vb
 Private Sub SaveComponent(ByRef oCommand As SqlCommand, ByVal compID As Integer)

    oCommand.CommandText = "LFS_Save_NPR_Total"

    For i As Integer = 0 To 12

        oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProvCode", FindProvCodeForSelectedTabIndex(i)))
        oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Population", sumDts.Rows(0)(i + 3))) 'change sumdts.rows(0)(i+3)... to NEW DATA TABLE?
        oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CompEstID", compID))
        oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        oCommand.Parameters.Clear()

    Next

    oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProvCode", FindProvCodeForSelectedTabIndex(13)))
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Population", sumDts.Rows(0)(2)))
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CompEstID", compID))
    oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    oCommand.Parameters.Clear()

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you will need to show at least the Save code.

Comment: will do @mary . will update

Comment: possibly storing those values in the data table in the First tab into an array, but the issue is I am not sure how to access those values.. because when accessing datatable, it goes to the last tab only..

Comment: It almost looks like you are generating primary key values in code instead of an identity column in SQL Server. Yes?

Comment: Clever, you found a Constructor for parameters that behaves like .AddWithValue. Lots of boxing and unboxing, inferred data types...Could cause all the same problems as .AddWithValue

Comment: compID is a Double?

Comment: compID is integer

Comment: the issue in this is when in the SaveComponent sub, when sumdts is mentioned, it is only referring to the LAST sumdts (data table) and so I cannot access the other data table created before.  because there are tabs that are created dynamically based on different dates in the excel file. so if the excel file has two dates, program will create two separate tabs, based on those dates. and when saving, referring to sumdts is only saving values of the last tab, the last loaded data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

My solution was to create an arraylist and store the datatables into those arraylist.
and when saving, save the arraylist.items into the database

Thank you to @mary for your comments and help